# what does "which" refer in the sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Many  electric  clocks  are  combined  with  radios,  which  can  sometimes  be  set  to  turn  on automatically.

In this sentence, what does "which" refers to, radios or electric clocks,or radios combined with electric clocks,or electric clocks combined with radio?

Comment: "Which" refers to the radios.  if you replaced the comma and which with "that", it would read "Many electric clocks are combined with radios that can sometimes be...", which might make it more obvious as to why.

Comment: Logically, turning the electric clock on and off would not make any sense, so it must refer to the radio.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Which" in the sentence ("Many electric clocks are combined with radios, which can sometimes be set to turn on automatically.") refers to electric clocks combined with radios as that was the last sentence proir to the pronoun "which" if you wanted to refer to them seperatly preferably you would remove the word "which" from the sentence altogether. In doing so you would have to say ("Many electric clocks are combined with radios, electric clocks and and radios can sometimes be set to turn on automatically.") However it would change the meaning of the sentence completly.